# Determine if one path is under another path in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have two paths: application root path and target path. What is the simplest way to ensure that the target path is the children of application root path?

Basically the target path provided by the user is to be displayed by my server. But I want to constrain my server so only the files under the application root path are displayable. So I want to check that the target path is under the root path.

The root path can contain nested directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
def child?(root, target)
  raise ArgumentError, "target.size=#{target.size} < #{root.size} = root.size"\
    if target.size < root.size

  target[0...root.size] == root &&
    (target.size == root.size || target[root.size] == ?/)
end

root = "/root/app"

p child?(root, "/root/app/some/path") # => true
p child?(root, "/root/apple")         # => false 
p child?(root, "/root/app")           # => true
p child?(root, "/root")               # => ArgumentError: target.size = 5 < 9 = root.size
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a bit inefficient, but foolproof

```
require 'find'
Find.find(root).include?(target)
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided any use case, thus I assume the following variables apply to your case

```
root =   "/var/www/"
target = "/var/www/logs/something/else.log"
```

You can use a regular expression or even more simple [`String#start_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F)

```
target.start_with?(root)
```

Comment: What if `target = "/var/www/.../.../etc/password"` ? Safer with `File.realpath(target).start_with?(root)`

Answer (score 1):

How about a regular expression:

```
root = "/root/app/"
target = "/root/app/some/path"

target =~ /^#{root}/
```

You could use `Pathname#realdirpath` to convert relative paths to absolute paths if needed.

Comment: Hmm I was thinking it should resolve stuffs like home directory or "~/../../../pwd". But I think this is workable.

Comment: I added a note to use a Pathname method to help with that

Comment: What if target is `"/root/apple"`?

Answer (score 1):

I like [`Pathname#ascend`](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/pathname#method-i-ascend) for this:

```rb
ancestor = Pathnew.new(path1).realdirpath
descendant = Pathnew.new(path2).realdirpath
descendant.ascend { |path| break true if path == ancestor } || false
```

(`Pathname#==` works by string comparison, so it helps to sanitize your inputs with `#realdirpath` first.)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid path injection you can use File.path method:

```
[21] pry(main)> path_1 = File.path(Rails.root.join('public', '../config/routes.rb') )
=> "/project_path/config/routes.rb"
[22] pry(main)> path_2 = File.path(Rails.root.join('public', 'robots.txt') )
=> "/project_path/public/robots.txt"
[24] pry(main)> path_1.include?(Rails.root.join('public').to_s )
=> false
[25] pry(main)> path_2.include?(Rails.root.join('public').to_s )
=> true
```

Comment: does this actually answer OP's question?